# Запрет восстановления Базы Данных

Tags: sql-server

Можно ли как-то программно отследить восстановление БД из резервной копии?

Ситуация следующая: В БД хранятся данные о платежах для отправки данных по чекам в ОФД. Если откатить бд, данные могут потеряться, а информацию по чекам отправлять второй раз уже нельзя. Как быть? Можно ли **запретить** восстановление или это решается только административными актами внутри конторы?

Понятно, что можно дублировать данные в другую БД. Хотелось бы более лаконичные решения.

Comment: Можно, например, хранить список "ведущих" (или "последний отправленый)" id  в отдельном файле или базе. Явно запрет врядли получится.

Comment: Если программа работает 24 часа в сутки - то можно проверять "активную последнюю дату" - тогда можно вычислить когда БД последний раз изменялась (можно учесть 8-часовой раб день, поправка на празники - усложнит, но если в 8:00 начали работу - то активный простой будет сразу виден) - и сделав вывод "простой 1-2 дня" - вычислить что БД старая.

Comment: @nick_n_a, нет, весь проект построен на двухуровневой архитектуре и работа клиентской части зависит от регламента конкретного клиента.Тем более специфика такова, что люди могли бэкапнуть базу перед "тяжелой" операцией, завалить её и тут же подняться. Но спасибо за идеи

Comment: Ну и что будете делать с заваленной базой при запрещённом восстановлении?) Отдельная база/файл с информацией об отправленном, судя по доступной здесь информации, видится наиболее адекватным решением

Comment: А восстановление чем или кем выполняется (клиентской программой или сотрудником)? Запретить по идее можно, но этим можно зацепить и что-то лишнее (зависит от архитектуры приложения). Вдобавок, достаточно привилегированный логин скорее всего сможет вернуть себе разрешения, которые у него отняли.